# Excel, SUM across all sheets not including last sheet when adding new row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a simple SUM for every corresponding cell from all 12 sheets (12 months) ranging from April 2023-March 2024

This works fine, but when I add a new line (a new customer) it only adds the SUM of 11 sheets (months), not all 12.

My formula is:

```
=SUM('10th April 2023:10th March 2024'!E15)
```

When I add a new line (to add a new customer) it changes to this:

```
=SUM('10th April 2023:10th February 2024'!E16)
```

The end of the formula for some reason won't stay as my final sheet name "10th March 2024" but my 2nd to last, "10th February 2024". This happens no matter how many new lines I add too.

I've dragged the same formula across the entire row, yet when I add a new table line the formula for the new lines changes to months April-February rather than April-March

Comment: If your sheets go from April 2023 to February 2024, how can you have 10th March 2024?

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo! It ranges from April 2023 to March 2024. I've been staring at numbers for hours lol.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Have you tried testing this with a different spreadsheet?

Comment: What does *"add a new line"* mean? It doesn't sound like *copy down*. Is this formula in an Excel table? Also, if you have *"dragged the same formula across the entire row"*, the cell reference should have changed to `F15`, not to `E16`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Hi, by add new line I meant: right click, insert, table row below (so it's an excel table too). The cell reference being E16 is the cell reference for the new table row below(so it would still be for the same column). I've dragged the formula across the row so each column counts the next line down in that same column when a new row is added across all the sheets. (I hope that makes sense). I've tried changing the formula to April - August and it still stays as April-Feb when adding a new row. So it's as if the formula is locked into the table or something?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It seems to work as intended on a new SS... although I need the current SS to work as there's a lot of other formulas and code to transfer etc. On my other reply today I mentioned it's an excel table and I've tried changing the formula to be April-Aug rather than all 12 months and it still remains as April-Feb, so it's nothing to do with the final month being broken but the formula itself being locked in as April-Feb in the table whenever a new row is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally worked out the answer to my own question!

I had to "clear contents" on my table and re-write the formula and copy it down.

Every time I added a new line to the table it was using the old formula and wasn't updating to the new one.

Clearing the contents of the table fixed this.